# Dynamic library dynamic attach

Tags: c, linux, makefile

**EDIT found an issue, but it still needs to be solved it should be below in answers** 
My task is to write app based on existing files. test.c(main) randapi.c randapi.h(2 functions in here) and initapi.c(one function). "how can You use dynamic library as dynamic loaded library. Using eg9 (where i made a dynamic library and it worked fine) write app where this libraries will be attached dynamic"

here is my try with a makefile but terminal says that :failed to open when i come to run file using ./program

i have tried also version without attaching initapi.c but then it says initRand is unknown besides that make file clearly attached it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ITERATIONS  1000000L

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  long  i;
  long  isum;
  float fsum;
  void *lib;

  lib=dlopen("librandapi.so", RTLD_LAZY); 
  if (!lib)
  {
    printf("failed to open");
    exit(1);
  }
  int (*getRand)(int);
  float (*getSRand)();
  void (*initRand)();

getRand=dlsym(lib,"getRand");
getSRand=dlsym(lib,"getSRand");
initRand=dlsym(lib,"initRand");

  initRand();
  isum = 0L;
  for (i = 0 ; i < ITERATIONS ; i++) {
    isum += ((*getRand)(10));
  }
  printf( "getRand() Average %d\n", (int)(isum / ITERATIONS) );

  fsum = 0.0;
  for (i = 0 ; i < ITERATIONS ; i++) {
    fsum += ((*getSRand)());
  }

  printf( "getSRand() Average %f\n", (fsum / (float)ITERATIONS) );
  dlclose(lib);
  return 0;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
makefile

  zad9: test.c
    gcc -Wall -o zad9 test.c -ldl
librandapi.so: randapi.o initapi.o
    gcc -shared -o librandapi.so randapi.o initapi.o
randapi.o: randapi.c randapi.h
    gcc -c -Wall -fPIC randapi.c
initapi.o: initapi.c
    gcc -c -Wall -fPIC initapi.c

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   zad9: test.c initapi.c
    gcc -Wall -o zad9 test.c initapi.c -ldl
librandapi.so: randapi.o initapi.o
    gcc -shared -o librandapi.so randapi.o 
randapi.o: randapi.c randapi.h
    gcc -c -Wall -fPIC randapi.c
```

Comment: What's the value in `errno`, preferrably translated by `strerror()`, after the `dlopen()`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line in `man 3 dlopen`:

> If filename contains a slash ("/"), then it is interpreted as a (relative or absolute)  path‐name.  Otherwise, the dynamic linker searches for the object as follows (see ld.so(8) for further details):

(and then a buch of rules that do not include the current directory nor the one where the executable is).

My guess is that you are copying `librandapi.so` to the current directory and that's why `dlopen()` cannot find it.

If that's the case, the solution is easy:

```
lib=dlopen("./librandapi.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Comment: all files are in one folder, but i tried it, didnt work

Comment: @RafałBolek: Are you running the program from its directory (`./program`) or are you doing it from another one (`src/bin/program`)? Because if you do the latter the so will not be found, you'd need `"src/bin/librandapi.so"`.

Comment: @rodrigoi: m doing this from its directory, i found an issue, when i separate makefile to both it suddenly works perfect meab You know the way to pull them into one keeping the good result?